# How to restrict and RESET <input type="number" /> in react w/ Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input with the type="number" which modifies the quantity of the item in the cart. The code is as below:

```
<input 
       type="number" 
       value={quantity} 
       onChange={ (e)=> {
            const regEx= /^([1-9]{1,2})$/;
            if ( !e.target.value || regEx.test(e.target.value)) {
                 dispatch(adjustQuantity(id, e.target.value));
               }
            }}
       className='value' />
```

As you can see, i'm using regex and i want to restrict the input in a way that only numbers 1-20 can be accepted. The problem is that it removes non-leading zeros too and numbers can be larger than 20.

I also need to make sure that the user can't leave the input empty, as if the user didn't enter a number or just left it empty, the value needs to be reset to 1 automatically after 3 seconds.

Edit:
Resetting the value is more important than restricting the range.
Thanks

Comment: Why not `parseInt(e.target.value, 10)` and see if it's `Number.isNaN()`? regex seems like a poor solution here.

Comment: if you want 1 to 20 with a regex it would be 0[1-9]|[1]\d|20 (if you don't mind forcing leading zero)

Comment: To match an optional zero and 1-20 use `^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)$` Your current pattern matches from 11 - 99

Comment: Not exactly the most aesthetically pleasing solution, but given it's just 20 possible values, consider replacing the field with a `<select>`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird it fixed the range of valid numbers, but how can i reset it?

Answer (score 1):

You can match numbers 1 through 20 using the following regex:

```
/^([1-9]|1\d|20)$/
```

*However,* I suggest that you parse the number and just do a regular comparison instead, since that kind of regex is hard to read and hard to maintain, let alone configure during execution.

```
const value = Number(e.target.value);
const notTooSmall = value >= 1;
const notTooBig = value <= 20;
const inRange = notTooSmall && notTooBig;
```

This allows you to clamp the values in a more user-friendly manner. E.g. if the user copy-pastes 2019, you see it's too big and can put 20 instead.

*Note:* Using `Number` constructor does essentially the same thing as `parseInt`, except that empty string `''` will yield `0`, not `NaN`. In any case, you need to cover all possible inputs in your handler and respond in a user-friendly manner.

**But – you may not need to do this at all**.

HTML5 inputs have attributes `min` and `max` that instruct the browser to take care of this in the best way it can. That may not work in outdated browsers, but you cannot anyways rely on browser-side validation - that's just to make things easier for the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i still can't reset the element which is my main problem. Also the min and max property don't work in my case. I liked your solution but this way user still can leave the input empty which is my main problem.

Comment: Use the `required` attribute to indicate a control is required. You should remember that not all browsers support all js validation techniques (and they may appear differently per browser, if at all), so you still have to implement controls in React/server-side. You can't reset elements at the element level, instead you do it at the form level.. You should listen for `onReset` on the form and then set the state of the form appropriately to default values